# Python - Print out once when hit the if-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, logic

So I have been trying to play around abit with monitor - For those who doesn't know what monitoring is - basically what it means is that you are checking something etc element, url or whatever in a certain time and check again if it has been changed.

What I want to do is that the program is doing a requests from the beginning to get the website URL - The url will automatic be redirected either to /password or without it.

Then what I do is to check if password contains the URL - If it does.. Make a print out that password page is up and then send to discord only ONCE while it can print out password page is up as command but it should only print out to discord **ONCE!**

Then opposite if the password changes from /password to no password - it should say password page is down and then print out that it is down and send to discord **ONCE** that is has been down

This is what I have done and

url = 'mrcnoir'

```
while True:
        try:
            password_page = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url))
            password_page.raise_for_status()

        except:
            print('Error checking password page! - https://{}.com'.format(url))
            continue



        else:
            # *************---If password up---**************

            if ('password' in password_page.url):

                        # Password page is up
                        print('Password page is up! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))

                        if not ('password' in password_page.url):

                            # No password page -> password page


                            # *************---Send to discord---**************

                            print("SENDING...1") #Discord function will be added later

                            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))


            # *************---If password down---**************

            else:
                # Password page is down
                print('Password page is down! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))
                if ('password' in password_page.url):

                    # Password page -> no password page


                    # *************---Send---**************

                    print("SENDING...2") #Discord function will be added laterthis print...

                    time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))

        # *************---Retry between 6-12 random.---**************
        finally:
            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))
```

The problem im having now is that it never enters the ***if statements***  inside the else functions meaning it will never hit the **"Send to discord" function** ...

How would I be able to make it go through so it sends to my discord (no function is needed right now, a simple print out inside the function is fine for now) only *once*?

It could been so I have made the if statement wrong aswell....

---

***UPDATE:***

Excuse me but I might have been tired, I just made this one and I think I might have done it correctly now

```
url = 'mrcnoir'
password = False

while True:
        try:
            password_page = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url), timeout=5)
            password_page.raise_for_status()

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print('Error checking password page! - https://{}.com'.format(url) + ' - ' + str(err))
            continue



        else:
            # *************---If password up---**************

            if ('password' in password_page.url):
                        # Password page is up
                        if password != True:
                          password = True
                          print('Password page is up! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))

            elif ('password' not in password_page.url):
                        if password != False:
                          password = False
                          print('Password page is down! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))
                          time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))

                         # No password page -> password page

        # *************---Retry between 6-12 random.---**************
        finally:
            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))
```

Comment: How many times are you ganna ask this question ? You asked it twice yesterday!

Comment: @user2413548 I never got the answer but I did cleared myself better now which I think is most understandable right now. I did relized I did ask my questions wrong last time which could be a confusion for other - now I have cleared myself and hopefully it is more correctly now :)

Comment: You do realize that you open an if-block by checking if 'password' is in password_page.url and then want to call your function only if 'password' is **not** in password_page.url? How's that supposed to work? At the point your code reaches the line `if not ('password' in password_page.url):` it has already been established that 'password' is in fact in password_page.url.

Comment: @shmee You are actually correct - I have made now and new update. does that look more correctly int hat case?

Comment: It looks better from a control flow point of view. However, if the PW page is down when you first enter the loop, nothing will get printed, because `password` is False already. The `elif` is unnecessary, the condition `'password' in password_page.url` can only have two boolean states, so `else` would suffice. The parenthesis around the condition could be removed, you don't need and use them in such a case in python. The `time.sleep()` in your `finally` block will always be executed, no matter what. Unless you want two delays if the PW page is down, you can remove that from the `elif` path

Comment: Oh yeah, I set the password = None instead which will print out in that case both up and down in the first. Then about the time sleep in elif and.. you are correct, I did not think about it.  Could been removed since they never access there as you said. I appreciated and hoped I could make this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you print the value returned by `raise_for_status()` and see what it is returning? because for a successful hit it returns `None` and it will never enter in the `if` block of the first `else`. Read here: [quickstart python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

```
import requests

url = 'https://mrcnoir.com'

res = requests.get(url)
print(res.raise_for_status())
print(res.status_code)
```

Output:

```
None
200

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Corrently - Thats the correct answer i'm getting. I might have done wrong at the beginning and I have made an update now :)

Comment: If this helped could you please, accept this answer?

Comment: Well I mean the page did work correctly - However that wasn't the answer I was looking for. My question was about the if and else statement sir. :)